unable to extract data from lds lidar
I have this lidar and I want to know how to use it with this library (wish version) the only information I know is that the lidar works with 115200 baud rate.
if anyone can help pls,
thank you.

which lidar is it? ... which manufacturer and which model? ... refer to the manufacturer's datasheet

that's the problem, i don't anything about it :[.

so, you do not know what your have? ... how is that a robotics problem?

man, i know that is a lidar and i tested it it's send a packet of data, but how to decode it, you need to look at the data sheet or something, and for me i do not know the exact version name of this lidar.
